# How to apply Latent Diffusion for 3D Binary Voxel Data?

Tags: variational-autoencoder, diffusion-models, u-net, latent-variable

Suppose we have a voxel of shape (60, 36, 60) with values 0 or 1 (1-occupied, 0-empty). What is the possible architecture of latent diffusion?